# How to customize bootstrap fixed navbar-default so that li elements align downward?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to customize bootstrap fixed navbar-default so that li elements align downward? Currently it is aligning at top by default. You can correct my code or show your custom works. You can also show me any repo on codepen jsfiddle or other sites like that.

Thank you in advance.
[image: I want it to display that li element in the position of box i have drawn to illustrate].

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="masthead">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="socialnav">
            <a class="btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/RetinaInc"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-spin"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" href="http://www.twitter.com/RetinaInc"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/RetinaInc"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/RetinaInc"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/RetinaInc"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <!-- /socialnav -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
                </a>

            </div>
            <!-- /nav header -->
            <div class="col-md-6 ">

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navtext col-md-offset-6">
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top -->

</div>
<!-- /masthead -->
```

Updates: Here is my Custom css - updated again

```
.navbar-brand{
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
}

 .navbar{
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 11%;
  margin-left: 11%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.navtext{
  position: relative;
  left:20%;
}
.navbar-default {   
  color:#ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#000;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px; 
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #33aa33;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
    width: auto;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-rgba(255,0,0,0.7) toggle {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .icon-bar {
    background-color:#33aa33;
}

.masthead {
  color: #000;
}
.logo {
  width: 40%;
}
.pull {
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Please add your css or create a fiddle of your existing code. :) :)

Comment: @VaibhavJain I have added CSS now. Please help me.

Comment: @VaibhavJain It uses the bootstrap css, so here's the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/w5L3Y/2/

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz. Yes you are right. One thing is surprising. On your jsfiddle link it is aligning down despite you have same css i posted but in my case it is aligning at top like in image above. Can you describe me how?

Comment: @Robin I can't quite be sure without seeing the actual fiddle, you seem to have a box below the menu links, maybe it has some padding space. Since the jsfiddle there is removed, here's another copy http://www.bootply.com/KYgjtiJrbL

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz  here is css missing part     .navbar-brand{
      width:auto;
      height: auto;
    }

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz  here is my fork please correct it. http://www.bootply.com/wRVqTa4WDW

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz thanks for .navbar-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}  Can you please fix the li elements that going away from the navbar?

Comment: @Robin That's caused by the `left:20%;` in your `.navtext{}`. It was somehow there in your original CSS so I thought you needed it.

Comment: Ya @ICanHasKittenz. so i just placed it with -5px. its working.

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz. It now rocked except at 768px . It work when greater than 768px and less than 768px but the nav li are staying at right top corner.. How can I fix it. I tried media only screen and (max-width : 768px) and (min-width: 768px){
 .navtext{
   position: absolute;
   left:-50%;}
} but don't works

Comment: @Robin In the demo that I linked, have you checked how it looks on mobile? You can view it by clicking on the mobile icon at the top-right. The navbar before 768px collapses and can be toggled with a button.

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz thanks for reply.. some way i managed to make it work for 768px.. Thank you lot for great support. You are amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to align text vertically next to an image is to:

```
.navbar-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Regardless of the elements around it, this makes the menu links appear to the right bottom corner.

However, this messes up our responsive menu a little so we are going to restore it back when viewed on mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   .navbar-right{
      position: relative; 
   }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/65mumTNFSj)**

Comment: navtext is just for not letting background go off the navbar when hovered